# i want to filter out those the same display data in my data table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

[**i want to filter out those the same records**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OPt3.png)

I want to filer records from data table and show only one record.

Comment: For future reference, on Stack Overflow, you can't just repeat your question three times and then link to an image.

Comment: Saying "I want to X" three times doesn't make X happen.  This isn't magic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `distinct()` method on your query. For example, `$users = DB::table('users')->distinct()->get();` See the documentation on [selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects) for more information.